# PicketLink configuration for 389-ds / Redhat DS to support entryUUID

Tags: ldap, redhat, picketlink

Currently trying to make my **PicketLink** configuration work with **Redhat DS(389-ds)** and seems like there is no support for **RFC 4530 entryUUID**.
Is it so? 
At least from 389 I can't find such attribute. Is there some plugin for the server available witch can do the trick?
Or is there known workaround? I think there was some bug about this, but It's not clear where is it no? At least entryUUID is missed from schema on 389-server.
How one can make Redhat DS (389-server) working with PicketLink's entryUUID? [#137 (No support for RFC 4530 entryUUID attribute) – 389 Project](https://fedorahosted.org/389/ticket/137)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug. **entryUUID** attribute is missing from **389-ds**, so PicketLink couldn't use this missed attribute and 389-ds can use :

> nsuniqueid

for the same purpose. This is actually corrected in **PLINK_2.7.0.Beta1** for working with system props, and in **Beta2** and **2.7.0.Final** to work with Configuration API, like so:

```
builder             
.named("default")                 
.stores()                     
.ldap()                   
.uniqueIdentifierAttributeName("nsuniqueid")
```

With this configuration and **2.7.0.Final** my **389-server**(1.3.3.1) seems to work just fine.